# Redirect most of the subfolders (with exceptions) of a language to the language folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all subfolders of a language to the language folder, except 2 URLs. 
For example :

```
http://example.com/es/folder1/
http://example.com/es/folder1/folder2/
except http://example.com/es/terms-of-use/ and http://example.com/es/privacy-policy/

should redirect to http://example.com/es/
```

I tried the following without success :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/terms-of-use/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/privacy-policy/
RewriteRule ^/es/(.+)$ www.example.com/es/ [R=301,L]
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^es/(.+)$ www.example.com/es/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: hmm it works perfectly. I don't understand because I'm pretty sure I tried this earlier lol. Anyway, thanks a lot!